# About pointers and strcpy() in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, strcpy

I am practicing allocation memory using `malloc()` with pointers, but 1 observation about pointers is that, why can `strcpy()` accept `str` variable without `*`:

```
char *str;
str = (char *) malloc(15);
strcpy(str, "Hello");
printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, str);
```

But with integers, we need * to give str a value.

```
int *str;
str = (int *) malloc(15);
*str = 10;
printf("Int = %d,  Address = %u\n", *str, str);
```

it really confuses me why `strcpy()` accepts `str`, because in my own understanding, `"Hello"` will be passed to the memory location of `str` that will cause some errors.

Comment: Get rid of the pointer cast in malloc.See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Why? Actually these 2 programs are running fine, I just don't understand why strcpy can take such parameter

Comment: use `%p` to print a pointer. also `malloc(15)` for `int * str` can create problems later.

Comment: Ok, I tried to get rid of casts and it worked the same, but my question is why strcpy accepts str which is a variable that contains memory address?

Comment: @SouravKanta unless you do not have C99 support, as in MSVC (the casts make for more portable code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, a string is (by definition) an array of characters.  However (whether we realize it all the time or not) we almost always end up accessing arrays using pointers.  So, although C does not have a true "string" type, for most practical purposes, the type pointer-to-char (i.e. `char *`) serves this purpose.  Almost any function that accepts or returns a string will actually use a `char *`.  That's why `strlen()` and `strcpy()` accept `char *`.  That's why `printf %s` expects a `char *`.  In all of these cases, what these functions need is a pointer to the first character of the string.  (They then read the rest of the string sequentially, stopping when they find the terminating `'\0'` character.)

In these cases, you don't use an explicit `*` character.  `*` would extract just the character pointed to (that is, the first character of the string), but you don't want to extract the first character, you want to hand the whole string (that is, a pointer to the whole string) to `strcpy` so it can do its job.

In your second example, you weren't working with a string at all.  (The fact that you used a variable named `str` confused me for a moment.)  You have a pointer to some ints, and you're working with the first int pointed to.  Since you're directly accessing one of the things pointed to, that's why you do need the explicit `*` character.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is called indirection or dereference operator.

In your second  code,

```
 *str = 10;
```

assigns the *value* 10 to the memory address pointed by `str`. This is *one* value (i.e., a single variable).

OTOTH, [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) copies the whole string all at a time. It accepts two `char *` parameters, so you don't need the `*` to dereference to get the value while passing arguments.

You can use the dereference operator, without `strcpy()`, copying element by element, like

```
char *str;
str = (char *) malloc(15);   //success check TODO
int len = strlen("Hello");    //need string.h header

for (i = 0; i < len; i ++)
    *(str+i)= "Hello"[i];  // the * form. as you wanted

str[i] = 0;   //null termination
```

Answer (score 0):

Many string manipulation functions, including `strcpy`, by convention and design, accept the pointer to the first character of the array, not the pointer to the whole array, even though their *values* are the same.

This is because their *types* are different; e.g. a pointer to `char[10]` has a different type from that of a pointer to `char[15]`, and passing around the pointer to the whole array would be impossible or very clumsy because of this, unless you cast them everywhere or make different functions for different lengths.

For this reason, they have established a convention of passing around a string with the pointer to its first character, not to the whole array, possibly with its length when necessary. Many functions that operate on an array, such as `memset`, work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's what happens in the first snippet :

You are first dynamically allocating 15 bytes of memory, storing this address to the char pointer, which is pointer to a 1-byte sequence of data (a string).
Then you call `strcpy()`, which iterates over the string and copy characters, byte per byte, into the newly allocated memory space. Each character is a number based on the ASCII table, eg. character a = 97 (take a look at `man ascii`).

Then you pass this address to `printf()` which reads from the string, byte per byte, then flush it to your terminal.

In the second snippet, the process is the same, you are still allocating 15 bytes, storing the address in an int * pointer. An int is a 4 byte data type.
When you do `*str = 10`, you are dereferencing the pointer to store the value 10 at the address pointed by str. Remind what I wrote ahead, you could have done *str = 'a', and this index 0 integer would had the value 97, even if you try to read it as an int. you can event print it if you would.

So why `strcpy()` can take a `int *` as parameter? Because it's a memory space where it can write, byte per byte. You can store "Hell" in an int, then "o!" in the next one.

It's just all about usage easiness.

Answer (score 0):

See there is a difference between `=` operator and the function `strcpy`.

`*` is deference operator. When you say `*str`, it means value at the memory location pointed by str.

Also as a good practice, use this

```
str = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char)*15 )
```

It is because the size of a data type might be different on different platforms. Hence use `sizeof` function to determine its actual size at the run time.